# Visual C++ debugger not showing return value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

When I single-step with the Visual Studio debugger through the following program, no return value is shown in the "auto" window for any of the `istringstream` method calls.

It shows the return value for `vector::size()` though.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char>{}.size();      //<-- debugger shows return value
    std::istringstream{"x"}.get();   //<-- no return value shown
    std::istringstream{"x"}.good();  //<-- no return value shown
    std::istringstream{"x"}.tellg(); //<-- no return value shown
    return 0;
}
```

Of course I run this in "debug" configuration, so the compiler shouldn't be able to optimize the calls away. I created the project using console application wizard without changing any project settings afterwards.

Should I file a bug?

**Edit:**

Another possibly related issue: I can't <kbd>F11</kbd>-step into any of the above `istringstream` methods. Debugger just steps over them as if I had pressed F10. Again, it works for `vector::size()`.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report of Visual Studio than a proper code problem.

Comment: I get return values for all of these calls in "Autos" window. Yes, VS2017.

Comment: @Tankor SO is not only for code problems, it's also valid to [ask about coding tools](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'm not sure yet if this actually is a bug or if it's a configuration issue. I'd like some people to confirm it first.

Comment: @AnT Which VS edition are you using? Community, Pro, Enterprise,...?

Comment: @zett42: Community.

Comment: @AnT Thanks, your comment made me check settings again and it turned out to be missing debug symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was an issue of missing *debug symbols* when dynamically linking to the VC++ runtime. After a default installation of Visual Studio 2017, for instance, debug symbols for the VC++ runtime are not available.

**Possible solutions:**

- statically link to the VC++ Runtime (project properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library: Multithreaded-Debug)
- enable Microsoft symbol server (Extras > Options > Debugging > Symbols > Check "Microsoft Symbol Server" and enter directory for storing symbols in the edit control below)

I think the issue did not occur for `std::vector` because it is header-only, so the code gets linked directly into the program executable. For the C++ stream library, much of the code actually is inside a VC runtime DLL.

Comment: Glad to know that this issue has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks for your sharing.